# How can I get the aggregation framework to work with referenced documents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4, aggregation-framework

I got the following document structure:

Profile `has_many` DailyProviders. DailyProvider `embeds_one` Friends. Friends has an integer field `count`.

- NOTE DailyProvider `embeds_ONE` since, I don't intend on storing an array of friends. Just an overall daily count. Friends was used more for 'readability'.

How can I use the aggregation framework to return the sum of all counts grouped by provider and date?

```
class Stat::Profile
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :daily_providers, class_name: 'Stat::DailyProvider'
  field :profile_id, type: Integer
end

class Stat::DailyProvider
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :profile, class_name: 'Stat::Profile'
  embeds_one :friends, class_name: 'Stat::DailyProvider::Friend', cascade_callbacks: true

  field :provider_name, type: String
  field :date, type: Integer, default: Time.zone.now.strftime('%Y%m%d').to_i

  validates :provider_name, uniqueness: true, presence: true, inclusion: { in: %w(facebook, linkedin) }
end

class Stat::DailyProvider::Friend
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :daily_provider, class_name: 'Stat::DailyProvider'

  field :count, type: Integer, default: 0
end
```

I tried:

```
Stat::Profile.first.collection.aggregate(
  { '$unwind' => '$daily_providers' },
  { '$unwind' => '$daily_providers.friends' },
  {
    '$project' => {
      '_id' => 1,
      'daily_providers' => '$daily_providers'
    }
  },
  {
    '$group' => {
      '_id' => {
        'date' => '$daily_providers.date'
      },
      'count' => { '$sum' => '$daily_providers.friends.count' }
    }
  }
)
```

But I get an empty `[]`. Does the aggregation framework only work with documents that are embedded in a single collection? Or can it work with referenced documents?

Comment: Because MongoDB has no joins?

Comment: Does that mean, the aggregation framework won't work with a schema structure such as this one?

Comment: MongoDB cannot follow references to other collections within a query or an aggregation function. Only the current/single collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB can't follow references automatically. [DBRef](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#dbref)'s are only a convention for the database drivers. They have no meaning for MongoDB itself.

MongoDB does not do JOINs - period. The aggregation framework can only work with a single collection at a time. This is also the case for most other tools like MapReduce. When you need to do a JOIN, you need to do this on the application layer: query the first collection, inspect the results, and query the second one based on them.

For this reason, MongoDB encourages embedding of documents in the parent-object instead of referencing them.